# MySQL table with 85 columns - Is multiple tables with joins better?

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on finalising a site that will go live soon. It will process up to 1 million files per week and store all the information from these files in multiple tables in a database.

The main table will have 10 records per file so will gain about 10million records per week. Currently that table has 85 columns storing about 1.6KiB of data per row.

I'm obviously worried about having 85 columns, it seems crazy but I'm more worried about the joins if I split the data into multiple tables... If I end up with 4 tables of 20 odd columns and over 500,000,000 records in each of them them, won't those joins take massive amounts of time?

The joins would all take place on 1 column (traceid) which will be present in all tables and indexed.

The hardware this will run on is an i7 6700, 32GB RAM. The table type is innodb.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If your schema needs 85 columns, and you really need all of them for all rows, then - probably - everything is all right. If, however you have 85 columns because you are actually storing various different types of data in a single table and for every row there will be more null columns than value columns, well then you need to get back to pen and paper.

Comment: Pretty difficult to give a definitive answer without understanding the data structures and queries you expect to perform upon them (e.g. will every query need to access all 85 columns, or can the data be partitioned to better fit the actual access requirements?).  As a general point, joins across indexed columns can use the index file to find the associated records; since MySQL indexes are usually B-Trees, in which searches are O(log n), it might not be as bad as you fear.  Why not benchmark some different approaches?

Comment: To me, you'll only have "too many columns" when you're at the limit of your database.

The important question is: does each row NEED each of those columns? You should also look into vertical & horizontal partitioning of tables.

Comment: Read up on data normalization. Impossible to answer this without doing a data analysis and explanation on N forms

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I hadn't even thought to benchmark... I have about 3million records in the table right now for testing purposes so I will split it and see what the times look like.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on the structure of your data. 85 columns is a lot. It will be inconvenient to add an 86th column. Your queries will be verbose. `SELECT *`, when you use it for troubleshooting, will splat a lot of stuff across your screen and you'll have trouble interpreting it. (Don't ask how I know this. :-)

If every item of data you process has exactly one instance of all 85 values, and they're all standalone values, then you've designed your table appropriately.

If most rows have a subset of your 85 values, then you should figure out the subsets and create a table for each one.

For example, if you're describing apartments and your columns have meanings like these:

```
 livingroom           yes/no
 livingroom_sq_m      decimal (7,1)
 diningroom           yes/no
 diningroom_sq_m      decimal (7,1)
```

You may want an apartments table and a separate rooms table with columns like this.

```
 room_id     pk
 apt_id      fk
 room_name   text
 room_sq_m   decimal (7,1)
```

In another example, if some of your columns are

```
 cost_this_week
 cost_week_1
 cost_week_2
 cost_week_3
 etc.
```

you should consider normalizing that information in to a separate table.